# Specify package name and output folder from Android-generated ant build file?

Tags: xml, android, file, ant, build

I dont want to hardcode the name of the package or where it lives when building an Android project with ant. Im using the build file generated by Android. What properties contain the output folder (bin) and package name (e.g. package.apk) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used an additional task to rename and copy the package file.

Comment: Could you share that task? Thanks!

Comment: @Maragues

`<target name="deploy-release" if="deploy.folder.present" depends="pre-deploy-release">
        <copy file="bin/app-release.apk" tofile="${deploy-releases.folder}/app-${buildNumber}.apk" />
</target>`

Earlier in the build file I set deploy.releases.folder, buildNumber, etc. I also added a pre-deploy task that creates the destination folder if it doesn't already exist. All of this runs from a Hudson / Jenkins build server. To copy across from our Linux-based build server to a Windows file server, we mounted the network share in Linux using Samba.

Answer (score 0):

extract that Apk file by Winrar . then let you know.